# Matlab API reading .mat file from c++, using STL container

Tags: c++, matlab, stdvector, mex, mat-file

I have to read some .mat data files from c++, I read through the documentation, but I would like to know how to handle the data in a clean and elegant way, e.g. using std:vector(modest .mat file size(10M~1G), but memory issues should be taken seriously)

My function is sth like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mat.h"
#include <vector>

int matread(const char *file, const vector<double>& pdata_v) {

MATFile *pmat;

pmat=matOpen("data.mat","r");
if (pmat == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file %s\n", file);
    return(1);
}
mxArray *pdata = matGetVariable(pmat, "LocalDouble");

// pdata -> pdata_v

mxDestroy pa1;  // clean up
return 0;
}
```

so, the question is, how can I make a copy from mxArray *pdata array to vector pdata_v efficiently and safely?

Comment: files are huge? memory could be an issue? what size of file are we talking about? `fgets`  and keeping track of the filepointer yourself seems like a plausible way to go then. Yes, its hard, but does not stress memory and its quite fast.

Comment: It's much easier to use `fwrite` from MATLAB and put the data in a simple binary format that C++ can simply read (or even memory map).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example of using the [MAT-API](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-c-api-to-read-mat-file-data.html):

#### test_mat.cpp

```cpp
#include "mat.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void matread(const char *file, std::vector<double>& v)
{
    // open MAT-file
    MATFile *pmat = matOpen(file, "r");
    if (pmat == NULL) return;

    // extract the specified variable
    mxArray *arr = matGetVariable(pmat, "LocalDouble");
    if (arr != NULL && mxIsDouble(arr) && !mxIsEmpty(arr)) {
        // copy data
        mwSize num = mxGetNumberOfElements(arr);
        double *pr = mxGetPr(arr);
        if (pr != NULL) {
            v.reserve(num); //is faster than resize :-)
            v.assign(pr, pr+num);
        }
    }

    // cleanup
    mxDestroyArray(arr);
    matClose(pmat);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v;
    matread("data.mat", v);
    for (size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

First we build the standalone program, and create some test data as a MAT-file:

```matlab
>> mex -client engine -largeArrayDims test_mat.cpp

>> LocalDouble = magic(4)
LocalDouble =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

>> save data.mat LocalDouble
```

Now we run the program:

```
C:\> test_mat.exe
16 
5 
9 
4 
2 
11 
7 
14 
3 
10 
6 
15 
13 
8 
12 
1
```

Comment: exactly what I expected! Just one point, why matGetVariable instead of  matGetNextVariable ? in case of multiple vectors reading from a mat-file, which is better?

Comment: @lorniper: I wanted to keep the example simple. Basically you use `matGetVariable` when you want to retrieve a specific variable by name. If you want to iterate over all saved variables in a MAT-file, use `matGetNextVariable` inside a loop. Check out the `matdgns.c` example that ships with MATLAB (look in the `$MATLABROOT/extern/examples/eng_mat/` folder)

Comment: Very useful for import/export functionality.  Nice!

Comment: @Amro is it only possible to use mat.h within Matlab itself? Can't we use it in a different IDE?

Comment: @Sndn sure you can. `mex -client engine` was [used](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/what-you-need-to-build-custom-applications.html) [for](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-on-unix-operating-systems.html) [convenience](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-on-windows-operating-systems.html), you can build the application yourself by specifying the required [headers and libs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/mat-file-library-and-include-files.html). Note `mex -v ..` shows the actual compiler calls.

Comment: @Amro Thanks. I added the library path and include file path to VC++ directories. And lib path to Linker's additional lib directories. Still get the linker error though. `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _matOpen`

Comment: The Matlab API link is now out of date. The current URL for the "MAT Data API for C++" is https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-data-array.html

Comment: @ToddGillette not quite the correct link, I updated the post with the right one

Answer (score 5):

Here's another idea.  If you're allergic to bare pointers in C++ code (nothing wrong with them, by the way), you could wrap the bare pointer in a boost or C++11 smart pointer with a deleter that calls the correct `mxDestroyArray()` when the pointer goes out of scope.  That way you don't need a copy, nor does your user code need to know how to correctly deallocate.

```cpp
typedef shared_ptr<mxArray> mxSmartPtr;

mxSmartPtr readMATarray(MATFile *pmat, const char *varname)
{
    mxSmartPtr pdata(matGetVariable(pmat, varname),
                     mxDestroyArray);  // set deleter
    return pdata;
}

int some_function() {
    mxSmartPtr pdata = readMATarray(pmat, "LocalDouble");
    ...
    // pdata goes out of scope, and mxDestroy automatically called
}
```

Idea taken from here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#incomplete

Comment: Great use of C++11 `shared_ptr` to simplify usage.  I'm making a note of this!

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the data pointer of the `mxArray *pdata` and then copy data to `vector<double> pdata_v`:

```
double *ptr = (double *) mxGetData(pdata);
pdata_v.resize(numOfData);
memcpy(&pdata_v[0], ptr, numOfData*sizeof(double));
```

---

ps1: Pay extra attention to that, in MATLAB, matrice are in col-major order. So if `pdata` stores `[1 2 3; 4 5 6]`, `pdata_v` will be `1 4 2 5 3 6`.

ps2: Change `const vector<double>& pdata_v` to `vector<double>& pdata_v` if you want to change its content.

Comment: thanks for ps1&2! may I ask, instead of memcpy(seems to me more c-like,is it err-prone?), is it safe to use sth like pdata_v(ptr,ptr+num_elements)?

Comment: @lorniper It will be safe if you use it correctly though it's more error-prone than C++ style you mentioned. :)

Comment: your solution succeed to compile but give 'segmentation fault 11', the way I mentioned gives error at compile time: "no match for call to (std::vector<double>)(double*&,double*)"

Comment: @lorniper Before that, make sure you have allocate memory for `vector<double> pdata_v`, e.g. `pdata_v.resize(numOfData)`.

Comment: isn't it memcpy(&pdata_v[0],ptr, numOfData*sizeof(double))?

Comment: @lorniper Oops, fixed. :P

Comment: your method works now! and if for some reason I have to avoid memcpy, within this function body, I can't use pdata_v(ptr,ptr+num_elements) which is only viable when declaring a vector,right? is there any other simple way to do that?

Comment: @lorniper: if you wanna use that syntax, you could call [`vector::assign`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/) as: `pdata_v.assign(ptr, ptr+num);` where `double *ptr = mxGetPr(pdata);` and `size_t num = mxGetNumberOfElements(pdata);`