# How do I access the values inside a MATLAB array using Cgo?

Tags: c, matlab, go, mat-file, cgo

Using the MatLab C API and Go's [Cgo package](http://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo), I'm attempting to read a 24x3000000 matrix inside a mat-file in my Go program. I'm able to successfully read the dimensions of the matrix but how do I access the values inside each cell? (The goal is ultimately to return this matrix as a slice to my Go program.)

```
var realDataPtr *C.double
var field *C.mxArray

fieldName := C.CString("data")
field = C.mxGetField(pa, 0, fieldName)

rowTotal := C.mxGetM(field) // outputs 24
colTotal := C.mxGetN(field) // outputs 3000000

// get pointer to data in matrix
realDataPtr = C.mxGetPr(field)

// Print every element in the matrix
for row := 0; row < int(rowTotal); row++ {
    for col := 0; col < int(colTotal); col++ {
        // This is where I get stuck
    }
}
```

For reference, [here's](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/access-data.html) the Matrix Library API for C

Comment: `mxGetPr` returns a pointer to a regular C array of type `double` with length 24*3000000, stored in column-major order

Comment: can you show us the part where you get `field`? Here is an example of reading a variable from a MAT-file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26241535/97160. If you want I can show another example (in C, I'm afraid I don't know Go), but it would help if you give us a bit more context where the arrays are coming from..

Comment: @Amro I've updated my code to show where I get `field`. For some reason `C.mxGetPr(field)` is returning null. According to the docs this means there is no real data. However, I tested `field`using the validation methods [`mxIsDouble`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxisdouble.html) and [`mxIsNumeric`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxisnumeric.html) and both return true.

Comment: Oh this could be it. It's not shown in my code but I'm using [`matGetNextVariableInfo`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matgetvariableinfo.html) which according to the docs reads header information only. I probably should be using [`matGetVariable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matgetvariable.html)

Comment: I'm using `matGetNextVariable` instead of `matGetNextVariableInfo` and C.mxGetPr(field) is no long returning null. However I'm still unsure how to access the values without using pointer auto-increment. Go doesn't allow pointer arithmetic.

Comment: correct, `matGetNextVariableInfo` gets you only the array header (size, type, etc.. ) but no actual data. Now like I said I don't know Go to answer your question, but can you use something along the lines of [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) in CGo? This seems relevant: https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/cgo#Turning_C_arrays_into_Go_slices (you define a Go "slice" header to wrap the underlying C array returned by `mxGetPr`. You can determine the length of the array using `mxGetNumberOfElements`)

Comment: just to clarify, the length in *bytes* will be `mxGetElementSize(field) * mxGetNumberOfElements(field)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, since I don't have MatLab. For example,

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

// Print every element in the matrix
ptr := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(realDataPtr))
for col := 0; col < int(colTotal); col++ {
    for row := 0; row < int(rowTotal); row++ {
        // This is where I get stuck
        elem := *(*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(ptr))
        fmt.Println(elem)
        ptr += 8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Matrix data in MATLAB are stored in column major order, which means that the columns of the data are stored in sequential order in memory (this is the opposite to C and similar languages). Thus, if you wanted to access the data sequentially in C (I'm not immediately familiar with Go syntax, unfortunately), you could do the following:

```
for(col=0;col<colTotal;++col)
{
    for(row=0;row<rowTotal;++row)
    {
        data = realDataPtr[col*rowTotal + row];
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `col*rowCount` not `col*colCount`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Does anyone know how to access the value inside realDataPtr using Cgo?